# .htaccess Internal server error when using RewriteBase

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

My apache2 server running on `macOS Catalina 10.15.7` throws an internal server error when I'm trying to use RewriteBase.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase ~/username/Sites/framework/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(app|assets|config|core|etc|uploads|vendor)

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: is that '~' serving some special purpose?

Comment: The '~' indicates the home folder. For more information check https://apple.co/2HckGUW

Comment: No, the "~" does _not_ indicate "the home folder", since a http server is a multi user environment. So there is no "the user", but only multiple users. So I bet it should actually be `~username/Sites/framework/` which is the standard unix notation for a users home folder, not only within a http server environment, and not `~/username/Sites/framework/`...